# Usemap attribut and JQuery in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I created a panorama using the HTML area and map tags and JQuery.
It works perfectly on Chrome / Safari / IE and Edge but unfortunately I have no result on Firefox.
After doing some research on the problem I guess it comes from the usemap attribute or I should have added a "#".
But when I do it I end up with an error : **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: map[name=#hotspots]**
If someone could help me it would be nice

Here's the code :

The error is on line 105.

Thank you in advance :)

```js
function boxDisplay(title,link,PrdImage){
 document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("PrdImage").src = PrdImage;
 document.getElementById("PrdTitle").innerHTML = title;
 document.getElementById("LinkPrd").href = link;
}

function closeInfos(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
}


(function($) {
 $.fn.panorama360 = function(options){
  this.each(function(){
   var settings = {
    start_position: 0,
    image_width: 0,
    image_height: 0,
    mouse_wheel_multiplier: 20,
    bind_resize: true
   };
   if(options) $.extend(settings, options);
   var viewport = $(this);
   var panoramaContainer = viewport.children('.panorama-container');
   var viewportImage = panoramaContainer.children('img:first');
   if(settings.image_width<=0 && settings.image_height<=0){
    settings.image_width = parseInt(viewportImage.data("width"));
    settings.image_height = parseInt(viewportImage.data("height"));
    if (!(settings.image_width) || !(settings.image_height)) return;
   }
   var image_ratio = settings.image_height/settings.image_width;
   var elem_height = parseInt(viewport.height());
   var elem_width = parseInt(elem_height/image_ratio);
   var image_map = viewportImage.attr('usemap');
   var image_areas;
   var second_shape;
   var third_shape;
   var fourth_shape;
   var fifth_shape;
   var isDragged = false;
   var mouseXprev = 0;
   var scrollDelta = 0;

   viewportImage.height(elem_height).removeAttr("usemap").css("left",0).clone().css("left",elem_width+"px").insertAfter(viewportImage);


   panoramaContainer.css({
    'margin-left': '-'+settings.start_position+'px',
    'width': (elem_width*2)+'px',
    'height': (elem_height)+'px'
   });

   setInterval( function() {
    if (isDragged) return false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.98;
    if (Math.abs(scrollDelta)<=2) scrollDelta = 0;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
   }, 1);
   viewport.mousedown(function(e){
    if (isDragged) return false;
    $(this).addClass("grab");
    isDragged = true;
    mouseXprev = e.clientX;
    scrollOffset = 0;
    return false;
   }).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("grab");
    isDragged = false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.45;
    return false;
   }).mousemove(function(e){
    if (!isDragged) return false;
    scrollDelta = parseInt((e.clientX - mouseXprev));
    mouseXprev = e.clientX;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
    return false;
   }).bind("mousewheel",function(e,distance){
    var delta=Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(distance)));
    delta=distance<0 ? -delta : delta;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta + delta * 5;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer,elem_width,delta*settings.mouse_wheel_multiplier);
    return false;
   }).bind('contextmenu',stopEvent).bind('touchstart', function(e){
    if (isDragged) return false;
    isDragged = true;
    mouseXprev = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    scrollOffset = 0;
   }).bind('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isDragged) return false;
    var touch_x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    scrollDelta = parseInt((touch_x - mouseXprev));
    mouseXprev = touch_x;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
   }).bind('touchend', function(e){
    isDragged = false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.45;
   });

   

   if (image_map) {

    $('map[name='+image_map+']').children('').each(function(){
     var  area_coord, area_fragment;
     var area_coord_sec, area_fragment_sec;
     var area_coord_third, area_fragment_third;
     var area_coord_fourth, area_fragment_fourth;
     var area_coord_fifth, area_fragment_fifth;
     switch ($(this).attr("class").toLowerCase()){
      case 'area':
       area_coord = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
       area_fragment = $(".area");
       area_fragment.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment.clone().data("stitch",1).data("coords",area_coord));    
       break;
      case 'area_sec':
       area_coord_sec = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
       area_fragment_sec = $(".area_sec");
       area_fragment_sec.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment_sec.clone().data("second",1).data("coords",area_coord_sec));
       break;
      case 'area_third':
       area_coord_third = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
       area_fragment_third = $(".area_third");
       area_fragment_third.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment_third.clone().data("third",1).data("coords",area_coord_third));
      break;
      case 'area_fourth':
       area_coord_fourth = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
       area_fragment_fourth = $(".area_fourth");
       area_fragment_fourth.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment_fourth.clone().data("fourth",1).data("coords",area_coord_fourth));
      break;
      case 'area_fifth':
       area_coord_fifth = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
       area_fragment_fifth = $(".area_fifth");
       area_fragment_fifth.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment_fifth.clone().data("fifth",1).data("coords",area_coord_fifth));
      break;
      }
      
    }).remove();    
    image_areas = panoramaContainer.children(".area");
    second_shape = panoramaContainer.children(".area_sec"); 
    third_shape = panoramaContainer.children(".area_third");
    fourth_shape = panoramaContainer.children(".area_fourth");
    fifth_shape = panoramaContainer.children(".area_fifth");  
    repositionHotspots(image_areas,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
    repositionHotspots_sec(second_shape,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
    repositionHotspots_third(third_shape,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
    repositionHotspots_fourth(fourth_shape,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
    repositionHotspots_fifth(fifth_shape,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
    }



  });
  
  function stopEvent(e){
   
  }


  

  function scrollView(panoramaContainer,elem_width,delta){
   var newMarginLeft = parseInt(panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft'))+delta;
   if (newMarginLeft > 0) newMarginLeft = -elem_width;
   if (newMarginLeft < -elem_width) newMarginLeft = 0;
   panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft', newMarginLeft+'px');
  }


  function repositionHotspots(areas,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
   var percent = elem_height/image_height;
   areas.each(function(){
    area_coord = $(this).data("coords");
    stitch = $(this).data("stitch");
    switch (stitch){
     case 1:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (area_coord[0]*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord[2]-area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord[3]-area_coord[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
     case 2:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord[2]-area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord[3]-area_coord[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
    }
   });
  }

  function repositionHotspots_sec(second_shape,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
   var percent = elem_height/image_height;
   second_shape.each(function(){
    area_coord_sec = $(this).data("coords");
    second = $(this).data("second");
    switch (second){
     case 1:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (area_coord_sec[0]*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord_sec[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord_sec[2]-area_coord_sec[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord_sec[3]-area_coord_sec[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
     case 2:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord_sec[0])*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord_sec[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord_sec[2]-area_coord_sec[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord_sec[3]-area_coord_sec[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
    }
   });
  }
 }

 function repositionHotspots_third(third_shape,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
  var percent = elem_height/image_height;
  third_shape.each(function(){
   area_coord_third = $(this).data("coords");
   third = $(this).data("third");
   switch (third){
    case 1:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (area_coord_third[0]*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_third[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_third[2]-area_coord_third[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_third[3]-area_coord_third[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
    case 2:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord_third[0])*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_third[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_third[2]-area_coord_third[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_third[3]-area_coord_third[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
   }
  });
 }

 function repositionHotspots_fourth(fourth_shape,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
  var percent = elem_height/image_height;
  fourth_shape.each(function(){
   area_coord_fourth = $(this).data("coords");
   fourth = $(this).data("fourth");
   switch (fourth){
    case 1:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (area_coord_fourth[0]*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_fourth[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_fourth[2]-area_coord_fourth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_fourth[3]-area_coord_fourth[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
    case 2:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord_fourth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_fourth[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_fourth[2]-area_coord_fourth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_fourth[3]-area_coord_fourth[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
   }
  });
 }

 function repositionHotspots_fifth(fifth_shape,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
  var percent = elem_height/image_height;
  fifth_shape.each(function(){
   area_coord_fifth = $(this).data("coords");
   fifth = $(this).data("fifth");
   switch (fifth){
    case 1:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (area_coord_fifth[0]*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_fifth[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_fifth[2]-area_coord_fifth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_fifth[3]-area_coord_fifth[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
    case 2:
     $(this).css({
      'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord_fifth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'top':  (area_coord_fifth[1]*percent)+"px",
      'width': ((area_coord_fifth[2]-area_coord_fifth[0])*percent)+"px",
      'height': ((area_coord_fifth[3]-area_coord_fifth[1])*percent)+"px"
     });
     break;
   }
  });
 }

})(jQuery);

(function(c){var a=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];c.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener){for(var d=a.length;d;){this.addEventListener(a[--d],b,false)}}else{this.onmousewheel=b}},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener){for(var d=a.length;d;){this.removeEventListener(a[--d],b,false)}}else{this.onmousewheel=null}}};c.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(d){return d?this.bind("mousewheel",d):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(d){return this.unbind("mousewheel",d)}});function b(f){var d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),g=0,e=true;f=c.event.fix(f||window.event);f.type="mousewheel";if(f.wheelDelta){g=f.wheelDelta/120}if(f.detail){g=-f.detail/3}d.unshift(f,g);return c.event.handle.apply(this,d)}})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* layout */
.panorama,.panorama-view{width:1000px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;border:solid 1px black;margin:0 auto;top:100px;}
.panorama,.panorama-container{position:relative}
.panorama-container img{height:500px;position:absolute;top:0}
.panorama .info,.panorama-view .area, .area_sec, .area_third, .area_fourth, .area_fifth{position:absolute;display:block}
.panorama .info{right:10px;bottom:10px}

/* style */

.panorama-view .area, .area_sec, .area_third, .area_fourth, .area_fifth{opacity:0.2;background-color:blue;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-9999px;}
.panorama-view .area:hover, .area_sec:hover, .area_third:hover, .area_fourth:hover, .area_fifth:hover{opacity:0.4!important;}
.panorama-view img{user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none}

html,body,div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,img{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
html,body{width:100%;height:100%}
body{background-color:#FFFFFF}
.round{border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px}

#box {border: 5px solid rebeccapurple;background-color: lightgray;padding: 35px 15px 5px 15px;width: 150px;height: 190px;display: none;position: absolute;bottom: 20px;right: 20px;}
#ClosePrdInfos {position: absolute;right: 5px;top: 5px;cursor: pointer;}
#PrdImage{max-width: 100%;}
.BlocPrd{text-align: center;padding-top: 30px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Panorama 360&deg;</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Panorama" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/panorama360.css" media="all" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('.panorama-view').panorama360();
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="panorama">
  <div class="panorama-view">
   <div class="panorama-container">
    <map id="hotspots" name="hotspots"> 
     <area class="area"  shape="rect" coords="2363,903,2531,1124" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau ','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')">
     <area class="area_sec" shape="rect" coords="3193,961,3392,1274" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 1','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')" >
     <area class="area_third" shape="rect" coords="1295,701,1388,930" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 2','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')">
     <area class="area_fourth" shape="rect" coords="1039,1027,1207,1243" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 3','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')" >
     <area class="area_fifth" shape="rect" coords="121,1084,289,1221" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 4','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')" >
    </map>
    <img usemap="hotspots" src="images/View_from_Sky_Tower_Akl_small.jpg" data-width="4996" data-height="1300" alt="Panorama" />
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
   <img src="images/Close.png" height="16xp" width="16px" id="ClosePrdInfos" onClick="closeInfos()">
   <img src="#" id="PrdImage">
   <div class="BlocPrd">
     <div id="PrdTitle">Titre ICI</div>
     <p><a href="#" id="LinkPrd">Voir la fiche produit</a></p>
   </div>
 
 </div>
 <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.panorama360.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I don't see that error. Maybe you forgot to include some libraries?

Comment: Oops sorry, i'll add CSS. It is supposed to add some blue square